# SFML setPosition()

Tags: c++, sfml

I have problem with my function. Im using SFML library and I dont know why setPosition() dosent works.
However, when I put setPosition() under function call, it works correctly. Any suggestions?

```
void foodRandPos(Sprite spriteFood,  int blockDimensionXY, int foodDimensionXY, int windowSizeX, int windowSizeY ){

int frameWidth = (windowSizeX - (2 * blockDimensionXY) ) / blockDimensionXY;
int frameHeight = (windowSizeY - (2 * blockDimensionXY) ) / blockDimensionXY;
int foodRandPosX = ( ( (rand()%frameWidth) + 1) * foodDimensionXY);
int foodRandPosY = (( (rand()% frameHeight) + 1) * foodDimensionXY);
spriteFood.setPosition((float) foodRandPosX + 300, (float) foodRandPosY);}
```

Comment: I'm finding this hard to understand, could you expand more on the part "I dont know why setPosition() dosent works. However, when I put setPosition() under function call, it works correctly" Can you please show the code for the example where you are using setPosition outside of the function call. Also remember to pass a reference and not a duplicate of the sprite your "Sprite spriteFood" should be "Sprite & spriteFood"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass the Sprite by reference into the function. You are copying it in your code and the copy is being moved by the `setPosition` call.

Change your function signature to

```
void foodRandPos(Sprite & spriteFood,  int  ... ){
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tips if you don't want to cast your value to float in your setPostion() you can use sf::Vector2f(). Like that you can put your two parameters in this one and they are automatically cast to float.

Comment: A "tip" which likewise could been made as a comment instead. Since this doesn't really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Just like Omera mentioned sf::Vector2f() allows you to put in 2 parameters, specifically (x,y) coordinates which makes it an easier implementation in your code. Then you can just pass the Vector2f as the position to set to.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Statement As Argument

```
sf::vector2f((float) foodRandPosX + 300.0f, (float) foodRandPosY)
```

Instead Of

```
(float) foodRandPosX + 300, (float) foodRandPosY
```

Answer (score 0):

> void foodRandPos(Sprite spriteFood,

you  pass by value spriteFood maybe you want to make this a pointer or a reference

```
    void foodRandPos(Sprite & spriteFood,  int blockDimensionXY, int foodDimensionXY, int windowSi)
```

when you pass an argument in to a function it will copy the value and send it to the function basically sprtieFood is treaded like a local variable once the scope gets out of the function it gets "deleted" so you don't want its value you want its address in this case you pass a reference to that variable